# Do i need a separate iMac for OSX Server on Mavericks

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-mavericks, osx-server

I am an iOS developer and I want to implement continuous integration in Xcode. 
I have received following email from Apple

> As an iOS developer, you can now take advantage of continuous integration in Xcode by creating bots with OS X Server for Mavericks that automate the process of building, analyzing, testing, and archiving your apps. As the bots do their work on the remote Mac, Xcode on your development machine displays the build and test reports. Bots can generate a regular release for your QA team, be configured to execute on every check-in, and even test your apps on connected iOS devices.

I have downloaded OSX Server for Mavericks and its like Application.

**My Question is can I install OSX Server on my development iMAC machine and implement continuous integration? Or I have to have a separate iMac for OSX server???**

Comment: I got detailed answer here http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107199/do-i-need-a-separate-imac-for-os-x-server-on-mavericks/107210#107210

Answer (score 1):

I am running OS X 10.9 and the Server.app on my MacBook Pro Xcode development machine with no issues. I realize that your question is specific to an iMac, but I would not expect any issues.

I have a few Integration Bots configured and everything is working fine. The server is building, running test on real devices, and sending me pass/fail reports via email.

Answer (score 0):

You can install OS X Server on the development iMAC. Configure the server and Xcode for Continuous integration.

**Guide:** https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/

**WWDC video:**
http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/415xx83xkyr55fj/415/415_hd_continuous_integration_with_xcode_6.mov?dl=1